# Is there any way to give the Pi hardware HEVC or AV1 real-time encode support?

Tags: pi-4, hardware, video, compute-module-4, pi-5

I’ve been working on a project for a while that requires streaming video off of the Pi over cell data with as little latency as possible. In my case the Pi4/CM4 does not have fast enough H.264 encoding capabilities to be able to work with my application but I’d like to be able to take advantage of the size and flexibility of the CM4 in my design.

Are there any solutions out there that would allow me to offload H.265 or AV1 encoding to a slave device over PCI-e? From the research I’ve done, I’ve only been able to find a few chips that can do HEVC encoding, and nearly all of them are either too slow to work real-time or are offered by B2B companies that haven’t responded to my requests. I’m starting to get the feeling that the only way this will work is through a dedicated FPGA or ASIC, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: To clarify, this FPGA/chip solution is to be baked into a carrier board I’m designing, I am not looking to plug a GPU into my CM4. The carrier board needs to be as small as physically possible while still accommodating the encoding hardware.